# Trying to change my pycharm project interpreter to conda

Tags: python, anaconda, pycharm

I have Anaconda installed and Pycharm as well.  I would like to access the Anaconda libraries in Pycharm (right now i am unable to import numpy, sklearn, etc...) into Pycharm.  I went to settings and Project Interpreter and selected conda.  Now it says its loading but its taking forever and I am not sure if anything is happening (see screen print)  Please can anyone help me so I can access the anaconda libraries in pycharm?  thank you!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2gXc.png)

If I still click "OK" to load the project interpreter I am still not able to import numpy after.  (please see second screenprint)  As you can see numpy is not found and I recieve an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d07an.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to the latest PyCharm version and send `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...** to PyCharm's support at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com, the log should explain why the IDE fails to load the package list.

Meanwhile, `ModuleNotFoundError` makes sense as you are using a conda environment (`C:\Users\samir\Anaconda3\envs\testproject`) which most likely lacks the package. Activate the env in the command line outside of PyCharm and install `numpy` manually, something like

```
conda activate testproject
conda install numpy
```

If you want to use conda environments read the relevant docs https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

The `venv` folder in your project is a "pure" Python virtual environment. It was created by PyCharm during the new project setup probably, which leaves us the following action points as @Back2Basics already said:

1. Do not select "New environment" on the new project screen in PyCharm unless you need it.
2. Do not store your custom code inside a virtual environment.
3. Remove `venv` unless you plan to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the screenshots.  Those were helpful in figuring out the problem.

It looks like there is a virtual environment in your project (the directory venv underneath your test2 project)

1. Click and drag your python file out of that directory by clicking and dragging test2.py to the test2 folder at the top.
2. Then delete the venv directory

Then try to re-associate the conda environment with the project (it looks like those directions were working for you)